# mssql_connect stopped working mysteriously

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux

I have a linux box that overnight decided to start acting up. I have two different errors that have appeared.

My php script runs the following:

```
$sql_connect = @mssql_connect($SQLServer, $SQLUser, $SQLPass) or die("Some message about this not working\n");
```

And I get the error:

> PHP Warning:  [IM002][0][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified in /var/php/autocreate-new-students.php on line 23

In a separate script, pointing to a different box, I run the exact same line (different server/user/password information) and the die message echoes back to me.

I verified username/passwords, updates, firewalls, logs, services.. There were absolutely no changes or installs to any box during the time period when it stopped working.

I was thinking there might be a certificate of some kind that expired, but I'm not experienced enough in Linux to investigate.  Any suggestions what may have caused this problem to appear?

Comment: How did this turn out over the last year? You have left that box unfixed? Did it fix itself?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your DSN changed, or your database was dropped. Most likely, the configuration file for your DNS disappeared.

Comment: I am on a Linux box that has ODBTP configured.

Comment: I should also note, that we restored the server to a snapshot from a day before it stopped working, and the restored server has the same issue.  It appears to be triggered by the date?

Comment: Sounds like a remote server issue. Are you sure you can still connect to your target database?

Comment: Positive. And it's 3 different servers it lost connection to, so all 3 would have needed to go corrupt at the same moment.

Comment: Then check your ODBTP config. Looks like your datasource definition is gone.

Comment: ODBTP has not changed since when it was working. I did just manage to remove that first error by installing sybase, and disabling the odbtp module. The calls to the other servers still fail with the message in die.

Comment: By fixing syntax in the other files, they now work with the sybase driver. Still have no idea what caused the problem, but I managed to work around it.